# Creating a Vaadin Theme

Tags: css, vaadin8

I want to create a theme very closely based on the default (valo) theme but with a few extra CSS rules.

I am following the basic instructions [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/themes/themes-creating.html%20here)

I have my own CSS under VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css

I have the annotation `@Theme("mytheme")` on my UI class

The css file contains:

```
@import "../valo/styles.css";

.my-additional-styles {...}
```

The rendered page picks up my additional styles OK but none of the valo style are applied at all. Looks like the @import is not working.

When I check the validity of the valo/styles.css URL in the browser, the correct css is retrieved.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I should be called styles.**s**css (without the asterisks). Also the included valo file should be scss.

Comment: FYI… themes are changing radically in Vaadin 10 (Vaadin Flow) from Vaadin 8. No more use of Sass. Previous themes no longer supported. A new theme “Lumo” is bundled. [Details here.](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/6-theming.html)

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: thanks, but I found a different way and no longer need to do this

Comment: Ok. IMO this question should be closed then.